var vs let for *globals*... what practical difference does "a property on the global object" make?
I have seen this (or similar):

At the top level, let, unlike var, does not create a property on the
global object.

many times.
My question is: what practical difference does this make ?
Or, to put it another way: is this a distinction that makes no difference ?
Or, is there some deep magic here which it would be useful to understand ?
For what it's worth, I found this definition (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_variable):

Global variable
A global variable is a variable that is declared in the global scope
in other words, a variable that is visible from all other scopes.
In JavaScript it is a property of the global object.

I assume the last sentence is simply out of date ?  Or is a 'let' global somehow a second class global ?

@0stone0 well, there are absolutely practical and very applicable concerns for global properties vs global variables that aren't properties. It's not random that const and let do not create global properties. It was a deliberate design decision based on failures of the past. Remember Using the variable "name" doesn't work with a JS object? It's exactly a symptom of this. let name works while var name does not. Because the latter is window.name. IMO we should care if and why our code works. I don't see how that is an opinion.

What is the practical detailed programming problem to solve?

@0stone0: it was probably a mistake to ask "why should I care ?".  I have edited the question to better reflect what I meant.  Thank you.

@Wicket: since I don't understand the practical difference between having and not having "a property on the global object", I'm not able to say what practical use might be made of that difference.  Sorry.

First of all, remember that not just your code is in global scope. It is the best practice to do your best to isolate code from the global scope before ES6 modules existed. So, a hand-wrapped module could look like:


/* some library code wrapped as a module */
(function someThirdPartyLibrary() {
  var myGlobal = "hello";
  
  setTimeout(
    () => console.log(myGlobal.toUpperCase()), 
    1000
  );
})();

/* /library code */

/* other code */

var myGlobal = 42;

console.log(myGlobal);



This works with the isolation. There are two different variables called myGlobal and both have different values.
However, the practice of wrapping with modules came after many times code not doing it properly. Which leads to hard to find and diagnose bugs. Consider the same but with no isolation to it:


/* some library code NOT wrapped as a module */
var myGlobal = "hello";

setTimeout(
  () => console.log(myGlobal.toUpperCase()), 
  1000
);

/* /library code */

/* other code */

var myGlobal = 42;

console.log(myGlobal);



Now there is an issue.
This is further compounded when new window level variables are introduced. Old code can stop working. For basically the same underlying reason - fighting over the same global identifier. Let us say it was not a library but just the browser introducing myGlobal:


/* imagine a browser update adds a new thing */

Object.defineProperty(window, "myGlobal", {
  value: "hello",
  writable: false
})

/* /browser update */

/* other existing code */

var myGlobal = 42;

console.log(myGlobal); //"hello"



This was a bigger problem in the past. Infamously with name Using the variable "name" doesn't work with a JS object)
A lot of window-level properties now play nicer as variables. However, it is still not recommended to use properties on the global object. This is why const and let create global identifiers but but no properties on the global object unlike var. This allows for code that will work since a global property and a global variable with the same name but declared with let/const are different things:


/* imagine a browser update adds a new thing */

Object.defineProperty(window, "myGlobal", {
  value: "hello",
  writable: false
})

/* /browser update */

/* other existing code */

let myGlobal = 42; //<-- now a let

console.log(myGlobal); //42



The property on the global object can still be accessed via the global object explicitly, if needed.:


/* imagine a browser update adds a new thing */

Object.defineProperty(window, "myGlobal", {
  value: "hello",
  writable: false
})

/* /browser update */

/* other code */

let myGlobal = 42; //<-- now a let

console.log(myGlobal); //42
console.log(window.myGlobal); //"hello"



let/const have other protections against mistakes as well, like an early error on redeclaration. But the separation of global variables and global properties is part of the package. All built on lessons from the past where clashing of globals for one reason or antother would lead to errors. Often hard to diagnose, many times completely surprising, as well. The lack of reliance on properties on the global object gives code much more resiliency when there are changes. Acting as an implicit isolation similar to what modules provide.
This is one of the many good reasons to avoid using var ever and only use let and const.
